Evaluate $\operatorname{nd}\left ( \frac{2K_6^\prime}{3},k_6^\prime \right ) \operatorname{sd} \left ( \frac{2K_6^\prime}{3} ,k_6^\prime \right )$
Could we get a simple expression for
$$
\operatorname{nd}\left ( \frac{2K_6^\prime}{3},k_6^\prime  \right )
\operatorname{sd} \left ( \frac{2K_6^\prime}{3} ,k_6^\prime \right ),
$$
$$
k_6^\prime=\sqrt{1-\left ( \left ( 2-\sqrt{3}  \right )  \left ( \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}   \right ) \right )^2 },K_6^\prime=K(k_6^\prime)
$$
where the $\text{nd,sd}$ are Jacobi elliptic functions and $K(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral?
I have came across a mess. That
$$
S=\frac{3^{1/4}\left ( \sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}   \right )\left ( \sqrt{3\left ( 2-\sqrt{2}  \right ) }  +\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2} } \right )  }{192\cdot2^{3/4}\pi}
\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{24} \right )  
\Gamma\left ( \frac{5}{24} \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{7}{24} \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{11}{24} \right )
$$
by elementary method equals to
$$
4K(k_6)^2k_6^\prime k_6^2\operatorname{nd}\left ( \frac{2K_6^\prime}{3},k_6^\prime  \right )
\operatorname{sd} \left ( \frac{2K_6^\prime}{3} ,k_6^\prime \right ).
$$
If we have calculated it, we can get an elementary proof for the singular value
$$
\mathcal{K}\left (  \left ( 2-\sqrt{3}  \right ) \left ( \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}   \right ) \right )
 =(\sqrt{2}-1 )^{1/2}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}  )^{1/2}(2+\sqrt{3} )^{1/2}
\sqrt{\frac{
\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{24} \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{5}{24} \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{7}{24} \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{11}{24} \right )
}{384\pi} }.
$$

One can use the third K formulas given in wiki reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions to evaluate your expression. The first task here is to find $s=\text{sn} (K/3,k), k=k'_6$ by solving a 4th degree equation $k^2s^4-2k^2s^3+2s-1=0$. Here $k^2=1-k_6^2$ but I am not sure if getting roots in radical form is easy. We further have $\text{dn} (2K/3,k)=(1/s)-1$ and $\text{sn} (2K/3,k)=\frac{\sqrt{1-\text{dn}^2(2K/3,k)}}{k}$.

Your expression simplifies to $\frac{s^2\sqrt{2s-s^2}}{(1-s)^2}$.
